# typescript same data type return from different classes

Tags: typescript

Hi so I have this structure for typescript, In the class implementer, I'm trying to return different classes but I have been told that it should work since they have the wrapper class takes care of the abstraction needed. There is an error that states this,

> Type 'MyGrandPa | MyGrandPa2' is not assignable to type 'ISomething'.
> Property 'doSomething' is missing in type 'MyGrandPa' but required in
> type 'ISomething'.

```
class MyGrandPa 
{
    private name;
   constructor(name: string){
        this.name= name;
   }
   get myName():string
    {
        return this.name;
    }


//   check what is returned here can be accepted as well
 
}

class MyGrandPa2
{
    private name;
   constructor(name: string){
        this.name= name;
   }
   get myName():string
    {
        return this.name;
    }


//   check what is returned here can be accepted as well
 
}




  class Parent 
{
    private dictVal= 'hey';
    private grandpa =new MyGrandPa('eric');
   
  get value():MyGrandPa
    {
        return this.grandpa;
    }
//   check what is returned here can be accepted as well
 
}
interface ISomething 
{

    doSomething(): MyGrandPa2; 
 
}

class Wrapper extends Parent implements ISomething{

    
   


    doSomething()
    {
        //Do something
        return new MyGrandPa2('new');
    }
    decider(message: string){
        if (message=="hey"){
            return new MyGrandPa2('new');
        }
        else{
              return super.value;
        }
    }

}


// import Wrapper
class myImplementer {

// why doesn't this work?
constructor(){
let myReturnValue: ISomething;
let wrapper= new Wrapper();
myReturnValue=wrapper.decider('hey');
}
```

Here is the error
[image: error]

Add more comments, Add more commentsAdd more commentsAdd more commentsAdd more commentsAdd more comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `myReturnValue` is of type `ISomething` which is structurally different to `MyGrandPa` or `MyGrandPa2` that can be returned by `wrapper.decider('hey')` as neither of them have a `doSomething(): MyGrandPa2;` method - which `ISomething` requires.

To resolve this, you either need to add a `doSomething(): MyGrandpa2` method inside the `MyGrandPa` and `MyGrandPa2` classes, or assert `myReturnValue` to an interface that would have a `{ get myName():string };` type.

To sum it all up, the core of the problem is that `myReturnValue` type is structurally different to the type being returned by `wrapper.decider('hey')` which breaks TypeScript's [type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) rules.